# How to set a JPEG's lat and lon coords with exiftool?

Tags: bash, shell, gps, exiftool, geotagging

Using `exiftool`, if I have a file named `foobar.jpeg` and the shell variables `lat="37.7708"` and `lon="-122.451"`.

What command do I use to set the EXIF metadata for that jpeg file such that its "geotag" / GPS metadata is set with those coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exiftool "-GPSLatitude=$lat" "-GPSLatitudeRef=$lat" "-GPSLongitude=$lon" "-GPSLongitudeRef=$lon" foobar.jpeg`

Because the GPS coordinates tags are unsigned, you need to make sure and assign the values to the relevant `GPSLatitudeRef/GPSLongitudeRef` tags as well, especially if the location is in the Western and/or Southern hemisphere. Even though these values would normally be set with `N/S` and `E/W`, exiftool well accept the raw values and figure out the proper Ref direction from that.

Comment: I finally figured this out on my own, but didn’t realize about the ‘ref’ aspect. Thanks so much!